# why we use pointer while creating object in C++?

Tags: object, pointers

here in this code we create two objects first is p1 and other is *ptr
i am not understanding how we create object by using pointer
can any one explain

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point {
    int x, y, z;
    public:
        Point(int x, int y, int z) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->z = z;
        }
        void display() {
           cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << endl;
        }
};
int main() {
    Point p1(10, 15, 20);
    p1.display();
    //here we create the object *ptr
    **Point *ptr;**
    ptr = new Point(50, 60, 70);
    ptr->display();
}
```

Comment: "i am not understanding how we create object by using pointer" You aren't creating a `Point` using `ptr`, you are assigning an unnamed pointer created by the `new` expression to `ptr`.

Comment: Specifically `//here we create the object *ptr` is not true. That statement creates the object `ptr`, and `ptr = new Point(50, 60, 70);` creates the object that can later be accessed as `*ptr`.

Comment: In C++, pointers are objects, `int`s are objects, arrays are objects. Not just things of a class type.